# upgrade App problems

Tags: ios, screenshot, upgrade

my App already on shelf App store. And now I want to upgrade it.

Before I upload new binary, may I first update the description in App store via iTunes connect ?

And will this updated description be shown in App store before I upload new binary?

I have changed the description but could not save because the old screen shot need to be changes its size.

But if I select " Cancel " button , instead of clicking " Save" , will my changed description be saved except the screenshot?

If my changed description is saved, then next time I only need to change the screenshot.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata for a currently live version of an application can be edited after logging into itunes connect -> Manage Your applications -> Your Application -> Current Version -> Metadata & Uploads Edit. Here you can make changes to description.[image: Please refer screen grab attached].

A new version of the application can be added by clicking on Add version, Fill up the "Version No." & "What's new in this version?". After This Click on your New Version & Edit Metadata for this New Version of application, this metadata will be available on the app store along with new version, once approved. [image: Refer image]

I hope this answers your query.